# Interpret Google Geocoding API Response returned to know which of them are accurate

Tags: google-maps-api-3

We have a program which calls the Google Geocoding API passing an address. we would like to understand for which of the address, the latitude and longitude values are very correct and for which of them it is approximated.

in the response, there are some tags like address_component which can have multiple "type" tag. there is also location_type under 'geometry'-->'location'

There is also 'type' directly 'result'

we are going which the following logic to understand if the lat and long are accurate.

Check for the multiple "type" under "address_components" and if we find either value "route" or "street_number" in any of the type tags, then it is very accurate.. should we use anyother tags from geocoder response  like "location_type" under "location" or "type" under "result" tags.

There is some information on Google Geocoding info, but did not figure out if there is a kind of logic we could apply.

Regards
Siva

Comment: There is also "partial_match" tag.. which of the above values in combination or one of them is appropriate to know that the address sent to geocoding is accurate

Comment: What is the question ?

Answer (score 3):

The `location_type` tells you the accuracy of that result, partial match tells you the geocoder did not return an exact match for the request.

See the documentation: [Results: location_type/partial match](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Results)

- geometry contains the following information:

  - location contains the geocoded latitude,longitude value. For normal address lookups, this field is typically the most important.
  - **location_type** stores additional data about the specified location. The following values are currently supported:
    - "ROOFTOP" indicates that the returned result is a precise geocode for which we have location information accurate down to street address precision.
    - "RANGE_INTERPOLATED" indicates that the returned result reflects an approximation (usually on a road) interpolated between two precise points (such as intersections). Interpolated results are generally returned when rooftop geocodes are unavailable for a street address.
    - "GEOMETRIC_CENTER" indicates that the returned result is the geometric center of a result such as a polyline (for example, a street) or polygon (region).
    - "APPROXIMATE" indicates that the returned result is approximate.

  **partial_match** indicates that the geocoder did not return an exact match for the original request, though it was able to match part of the requested address. You may wish to examine the original request for misspellings and/or an incomplete address.

  Partial matches most often occur for street addresses that do not exist within the locality you pass in the request. Partial matches may also be returned when a request matches two or more locations in the same locality. For example, "21 Henr St, Bristol, UK" will return a partial match for both Henry Street and Henrietta Street. Note that if a request includes a misspelled address component, the geocoding service may suggest an alternative address. Suggestions triggered in this way will also be marked as a partial match.

Comment: Reading the notes above, Geocoding v3 and changes from v2 to v3 : we are planning to implement the following logic to verify the address is accurate upto the street address level:

If there are more than one result tag in the geocode response then the address is ambigious and lat and long could not be accurate
If location_type is ROOFTOP in the geocode response , the address is very accurate.
IF the LOCATION_TYPE =GEOMETRIC_CENTER and partial_match tag is not true in the geocode response then the address is accurate upto the street address. 

please let me know if we need to consider anything

Comment: guess, we need to consider RANGE_INTERPOLATED also.. Any suggestions on the issue would be helpful